# Remove remote playlists from Amarok

Tags: amarok

I've just installed KDE to test it, so Amarok too. And this player tries to fetch some remote playlists. Even after removing all Internet services plugins, three providers remain: CoolStreams, Free Music Charts and Librivox.org

I don't want them. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Configure Amarok</kbd> → <kbd>Scripts</kbd> and uncheck